# How to get collection of elements which has not attribute?

Tags: jquery

How to get collection of elements which has not attribute with JQuery?

I want to find **links** which contain image which has not alt attribute.

Should I use something like this?
`$('a>img[alt!=""]')`

**Edit:**

I have found a work around it. There is a method .has which can detect if there is a child tag. But in my project I am deriving the selector from a string which is split. That would lead to problems using .has.

```
var selectors = 'a.mark-video;a.sp5;a>img[alt!=""]'
selectors = selectors.split(";").join(", ");
$(selectors).each(
function(){
   var current = this;
   if (this.nodeName == "IMG")
     {
     current = this.parentNode;
     if (current.nodeName != "A")
       current = this.parentNode;
     if (current.nodeName != "A")
       return false;
     current = $(current);
     }
  }
);
```

In the function I look to the parent if it is a. I used the "a>img" selector in different way than it is expected in JQuery but this is in the project where I try to search for links not images so it makes sense that I am not looking for images...

Comment: this should work. Please have a look at this doc https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Comment: are you getting error while using this?

Comment: it actually does not return collection of links but collection of images...

Comment: could you please post your HTML. It will be easy to help you with that.

Comment: I am using webextenstions API in Firefox to test this code. I have injected the script to this site: http://zpravy.idnes.cz/zahranicni.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this : Use `:not` with attribute name in square bracket, see below code

```
$('a > img:not[alt]')
```

Note: put one space before and after of `>`

Comment: Thank you. I also wanted to try something like this but I was not able to find out how to use the not operator.

Comment: Currently I am trying to use this `a.mark-video, a.sp5, a > img:not[alt]` string as selector and I got very strange error in debugger.  `$(selectors_).each(
    function(){
       var test = this;
      }
    );
    }` **error**: Exception - type error - selector is undefined. **stack**: `jquery-3.0.0.js:1915:5Sizzle</Sizzle.selectors.filter.PSEUDO;jquery-3.0.0.js:1882:12matcherFromTokens;jquery-3.0.0.js:2423:;jquery-3.0.0.js:2577:13` (shortened) I run the JQuerr on webextension API in Firefox so am not sure if this bug is in Firefox or in JQuery.

Comment: seems like JQuery refuses the :not operator. Without it there is no error

Comment: it should not ... which version you are using?

Comment: 3.0.3 as written in the error. But I have found a workaround see my updated question.